# Why does AtomicUsize not implement Send?

Tags: rust

`std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize` implements `Sync` which means immutable references are free of data races when shared between multiple threads. Why does `AtomicUsize` not implement `Send`? Is there state which is linked to the thread that created the atomic or is this a language design decision relating to the way atomics are intended to be used i.e. via a `Arc<_>` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a trick! `AtomicUsize` *does* implement `Send`:

```
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize;

fn checker<T>(_: T) where T: Send {}

fn main() {
    checker(AtomicUsize::default());
}
```

In fact, there's even an [automated test that ensures this is the case](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.8.0/src/test/run-pass/sync-send-atomics.rs).

#### Rust 1.26

[These *auto traits* are now documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html#synthetic-implementations), thanks to a [change made to rustdoc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/47833).

#### Previous versions

The gotcha lies in how `Send` is implemented:

> This trait is automatically derived when the compiler determines it's appropriate.

This means that Rustdoc doesn't know that `Send` is implemented for a type because most types don't implement it explicitly.

This explains why `AtomicPtr<T>` shows up in the implementers list: it has a special implementation that ignores the type of `T`.